# Modelo de relacionamento e entidade

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, entidade-relacionamento

Rapaziada, estou montando um website que possui a tabela de artistas e um artista pode tocar mais de um gênero musical, como eu faria para colocar no banco de dados os gêneros que o artista toca ?

Comment: Será necessário criar uma terceira tabela para intermediar o relacionamento de muitos para muitos.

Onde o artista poderá ter um ou vários gêneros e um gênero poderá ter nenhum ou vários artistas.

https://suporte.scriptcase.com.br/pt-br/article/598-relacionamento-n-para-n

Comment: Obrigado Thiago, só uma dúvida, na terceira tabela não terá chave primaria ? Apenas as duas estrangeiras ?

Comment: @ThiagoPires ....

Comment: Estou preparando um exemplo para te mostrar, na verdade a terceira tabela tera uma chave primaria composta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui está as tabelas que eu criei para exemplificar.

Por favor desconsidere as os nomes, visto que fiz um pouco correndo.

Aqui crio minha tabela de artista

```
CREATE TABLE artistaMusica(
id_artista SERIAL,
nome VARCHAR(10),
 PRIMARY KEY(id_artista)
)
```

Aqui os gêneros

```
CREATE TABLE generoMusica(
id_genero SERIAL,
nome_genero VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(id_genero)
)
```

Aqui a tabela responsável por fazer a ligação entre as tabelas

```
CREATE TABLE genero_artistaMusica(
id_artista INT,
id_genero INT,
CONSTRAINT pk_genero_artista_id_artista PRIMARY KEY(id_artista,id_genero),

 FOREIGN KEY (id_genero)
REFERENCES  generoMusica(id_genero),

  FOREIGN KEY (id_artista)
REFERENCES  artistaMusica(id_artista)

)
```

**Alguns pontos:**

1. A relação que eu criei seria assim, um artista pode ter nenhum ou vários gêneros, e um gênero pode ter nenhum ou vários artistas.

   2. Por isso criei uma Chave Primaria composta, para evitar dados duplicados, do tipo que o mesmo artista esteja inserido duas vezes com o mesmo gênero.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado, agora é tentar colocar chave estrangeira no phpmyadmin, kkk

Comment: Opa, vlw. Aqui tem  vídeo que embora em inglês, acho que pode ajudar
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A42FG4LzdbY